# Filtering of elements

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem filtering my array of elements, let's say.

```
Box
 -[Zombies]
 -[Players]
 -[Weapons]
```

I have a bunch of boxes which can contain all of the arrays listed above.

```
[Box]
```

Now I want to filter out the boxes that have whatever I want to filter out.
If I choose a specific zombieId + playerId, I will only get the boxes with those etc.

I tried using something like:

```
let filteredBoxes = boxes.filter { (box) -> Bool in

selectedZombies.contains(where: { $0.zombieId == box.zombies.zombieId }) 
&&
selectedPlayers.contains(where: { $0.playerId == box.players.playerId }) 
&&
selectedWeapons.contains(where: { $0.weaponId == box.weapons.weaponId })
    }
```

This works, but requires the user to select all 3 filters before anything is shown.

I also want to show the boxes that matches the users selection even if they only select some filters for i.e. selected zombies.

Comment: You mean you are having some filter option choose by User if user select only `Zombie` and `Weapon` then need to filter on that two only ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter the specific condition you can make it like this, declare 3 instance property of type `Bool` to control which filter user currently allow and use it with `filter`.

```
var filterZombie = true
var filterPlayer = true
var filterWeapon = false
//So now filterZombie and filterPlayer is true you want to filter only these two condition so make filter like this
let filterArray = boxes.filter { (box) -> Bool in
    let zombieResult = filterZombie ? selectedZombies.contains(where: { $0.zombieId == box.zombies.zombieId }) : true //Set default result as true 
    let playerResult = filterPlayer ? selectedPlayers.contains(where: { $0.playerId == box.players.playerId }) : true //Set default result as true 
    let weaponResult = filterWeapon ? selectedWeapons.contains(where: { $0.weaponId == box.weapons.weaponId }) : true //Set default result as true 
    return zombieResult && playerResult && weaponResult
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I used so much time on this o.O.